# Module not found error in PyCharm, but it is installed as an Anaconda package

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) 3 and [PyCharm Community Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) after that. I am able to chose the interpreter to be a [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment. But when I try using certain packages, such as [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib), it throws "Module not found error". When I run pip, it returns saying that matplotlib *is* available.

```
pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Clearly the package is there and for some reason it does not show up.

Comment: Found the solution. Went to Pycharm --> Preferences --> Python Interpreter 1) Removed all interpreters 2) selected "existing interpreter" and pointed to ~/anaconda3/bin/python and all the packages installed with Anaconda3 are loaded. Pheww!!!

Comment: for me deleting all conda envs except the one I wanted stopped pycharm getting confused when I selected the actual conda env I wanted to use...odd!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently the naming of the selection depends on the operating system, but the Python interpreter can be selected as follows:

- Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Project* → *Python Interpreter* (macOS)
- Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Project* → *Python Interpreter* (Windows and Linux)

Using the dropdown, select the right Python interpreter. Depending on your OS and setup, this can be the default interpreter (e.g., `~/anaconda3/bin/python`) or the interpreter corresponding to the Conda environment of your choice (e.g., `C:\users\username\.conda\envs\projectname\python.exe`).

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm Settings]

Now all the packages installed with Anaconda should be listed.

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm Preferences listing packages installed]

Comment: Yeah guys, don't create a "New Environment".
Anaconda is an "Existing Environment" since it already contains all the packages. 
You don't want to create a "New Environment" and try to install all those packages yourself...

Comment: I do not see  Preferences in Pycharm. Do you mean Settings/Project/Python Interpreter?

Comment: @[Sander Heinsalu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137029/sander-heinsalu) That probably depends on your OS. Apparently "Preferences" with MacOS and "Settings" with Windows.

Comment: Anaconda itself is not an environment. Anaconda's default `base` environment is.

Answer (score 3):

With Python 2019.2.3, (CE) there are the following steps on a Windows 10 system:

1. Go to *File* → *Settings* in the menu bar or alternatively press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Go to to the entry *Project* → *Project Interpreter*

   [image: Step 1]
3. Select *Show All* in the dropdown menu:

   [image: Step 2]
4. If your Conda Environment is not listed, press the `+` button and select **Conda Environment** on the left:

   [image: Step 3]

   Now select the desired environment by opening the dropdown menu *Interpreter* and click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Now your Conda environment should be listed as project interpreter. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the window and click <kbd>Apply</kbd> in the settings window.

Comment: On Windows 10, Python 3.9, Anaconda3, I see Interpreter: <No interpreter> and clicking on it shows an empty dropdown menu. I have tried creating several new and existing environments but the simple scripts I have do not run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to PyCharm → *Preferences* → *Python Interpreter*.
Select the *Use Conda Package Manager* symbol (green circle).

After it refreshes, select the *Install* (^N) symbol.
Search for the installed package

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing didn't help. It was already there.

`pip3 install matplotlib`

> Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.0.2)

[PyCharm → *Preference* → *Default Interpreter*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUUPP.png)

So, I had to change the default interpreter and then it started working.