# in ubuntu pycharm I can't find anaconda packages

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, anaconda

I have associated the pycharm and anaconda in ubuntu, but curious in pycharm's `Project Interpreter` I can't find all the conda's packages. Here it's the pics:
[image]
[image]

I can't find `pandas` `numpy`  in pycharm that we usually use in conda, but in the terminal when I use `conda list` I can see a lot of packages(`pandas` `numpy`)

When I google this problem, I can't find a solution, please help me. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first image,you have to choose the second option **"Existing environment"** as shown below [image] and then browse to the path where you have your anaconda installed. What you are currently doing is creating a new virtual environment. That is the reason you are unable to see all the packages

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't upvote, because of my reputation less 15
Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I have the same problem -  tried the suggested solution but no luck, any hint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097715/module-not-found-error-in-pycharm-but-it-is-installed-as-anaconda-package  -- similar solution - worked for me only after creating the project and then setting again the interpreter